# Discussion Forum v3.1.21 on EE v2.11.7 - users cannot unsubscribe from threads

Tags: forum, discussion

When a user tries to unsubscribe from a thread they get the following message...

The following errors were encountered
You are not authorized to perform this action

It does this whether you are a standard member or super admin logged in!!

I simply cannot find anything in the settings stopping unsubscribing??

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: This is the result when they click the link in the email?

Comment: No this is when they try to unsubscribe froma  thread in the discussion forum on the page

Comment: Did you ever solve this?